# Is there a way to find about with which switches a mingw build is built?

Tags: gcc, mingw

Is there a way to find about a specific gcc build that with which switches it is being built?
I heard that when building a gcc build out of its source code , there are couple of switches which determines some specific features to be available or not e.g there are `Thread_posix` and/or `Win32_thread` switches for building `MingW` on `Windows`,the first one would allow for using  std::thread and the other would not, or `sjlj` build vs `dwarf` builds which deals with exceptions ( i don't even have any idea what they are for! i only know that `sjlj` build is 15% slower in all cases!)
So is there away that i can do to know about these and possibly more information in this regard?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. The output of `gcc -v` shows you all you want to know.

The exceptions are like this:

- dwarf: `--enable-dw2-exceptions`
- sjlj: `--enable-sjlj-exceptions` or nothing for pre-4.8 64-bit MinGW-w64 GCC.
- seh: `--enable-seh-exceptions` or nothing for GCC 4.8+ 64-bit MinGW-w64 GCC.

These can be deduced from the libgcc DLL name, which always contains `sjlj`, `dw2`, or `seh`.

The threading implementation used in libgcc:

- win32: the default, optionally `--enable-threads=win32`
- posix: `--enable-threads=posix`

These cannot be deduced from a filename as far as I'm aware.

Comment: Thanks when i try to run gcc -v i get the "Program too big to fit in memory" error ! what should i do ?

Comment: It should print something like [this](http://ideone.com/0bKXqx). The toolchain I think you have (http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingwbuilds/files/host-windows/releases/4.8.0/32-bit/threads-posix/dwarf/) prints this on my system.

Comment: Thanks, i restarted my system and tried again and it worked just fine :) How come you guys know all of these stuff ?!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow.com, where there is (almost) always someone that knows what you want to know. `;-)` In my case, I build MinGW-w64 toolchains (binutils+GCC+gdb, and Clang), so I figured this all out.

Answer (score 3):

On Windows, using recent GCC versions (post 4.8) things go as follows:

1. For exception handling models `dwarf/sjlj/seh`:

   - win32 targeted builds

     1. For `dwarf2`

        - `--with-dwarf2` should be specified
     2. For `sjlj`

        - `--enable-sjlj-exceptions` should be specified
        - `--disable-sjlj-execptions` can be used as well in case you want to force disabling `sjlj` exception handling
   - win64 targeted builds

     1. For `seh`

        - Nothing needs to be specified. This is the default in case `sjlj` is not used.
     2. For `sjlj`

        - `--enable-sjlj-exceptions` should be specified
        - `--disable-sjlj-execptions` can be used as well in case you want to force disabling `sjlj` exception handling

     - **Note:** The default on `win64` if no exception handling arguments were passed to the configure script is `seh` exceptions
2. For the threading model `win32/posix`:

   1. For `win32`

      - `--enable-threads=win32` should be specified
      - **Note**: `win32` is the default threading model if no threading related arguments were passed to the configure script
   2. For `posix`

      - `--enable-threads=posix` should be specified

To figure out the exception handling model of an already built MinGW GCC:

1. If the MinGW GCC being looked at was built using `--enable-shared`

   - The `bin` folder would have `libgcc` as a DLL
   - The `libgcc` DLL will have a prefix indicating the exception handling model that is being used which would be one of the `dw2/seh/sjlj`
2. If the MinGW GCC being looked at was built using `--disable-shared`, it gets a bit more complicated and you can use one of the following methods:

   1. Manually use a combination of `strings` and `grep` commands to figure it out from the static `libgcc.a` will be available at `<GCC_buildroot>/lib/gcc/<target>/<version>/libgcc.a`, this time it wouldn't have the exception handling model prefix

      - `strings <GCC_buildroot>/lib/gcc/<target>/<version>/libgcc.a | grep personality` the output would include one of the following:

        1. `sjlj`: `__gcc_personality_sj0`
        2. `dwarf2`: `__gcc_personality_v0`
        3. `seh`: `__gcc_personality_seh0`
   2. Manually check for macros defined by GCC that indicate the exception handling model **(not favored)**

      - `g++ -dM -E -x c++ - < /dev/null` one of the following should exist

        1. `sjlj`: `#define __USING_SJLJ_EXCEPTIONS__ 1`
        2. `seh` : `#define __SEH__ 1`
        3. `dwarf2`: `#define __GCC_HAVE_DWARF2_CFI_ASM 1` **(not so sure about this one)**

Comment: Does this mean that on current GCC versions targeting Win64 `__try` can be replaced by `try`?